# PrimeNG multiselect not binding in Model Driven form when pulling "typed" data from server

Tags: primeng

I am using PrimeNG Multiselect in a reactive Angular form.

I can see the array of values coming back from the server through the chrome dev tool, but I cant figure out how to get it to bind to the multi select.

module is imported in the component and the app module:

```
import { MultiSelectModule } from 'primeng/multiselect';
```

template:

```
    <p-multiSelect [options]="activities" [optionLabel]="ActivityName" [panelStyle]="{minWidth: '300px'}" [showHeader]="true" formControlName="selectedActivities"></p-multiSelect>
```

Class:

```
export class ChemicalEditComponent implements OnInit {
  activities: ActivityType[];
  selectedActivities: ActivityType[];

    constructor(
        private _chemicalService: ChemicalService,
        private fb: FormBuilder
    ) {
        this.getActivities();
        this.getSelectedActivities();
        this.createForm();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.getChemical();
    }

    getActivities(): void {
        this._chemicalService.getActivities().subscribe(result => this.activities = result);
    }

  getSelectedActivities(): void {
    this._chemicalService.getActivitiesByChemical(this.chemicalId).subscribe(result => this.selectedActivities = result);
  }

  createForm() {
    this.chemicalForm = this.fb.group({
      brandName: '',
      commonName: '',
      formulation: '',
      selectedActivities: ''
    });
  }

  rebuildForm() {
    this.chemicalForm.reset({
      brandName: this.chemical.BrandName,
      commonName: this.chemical.CommonName,
      formulation: this.chemical.Formulation,
      selectedActivities: this.selectedActivities
    });
  }
```

The json returned from the server looks like this:

```
0:{ActivityTypeId: 61, ActivityName: "Driving"}
1:{ActivityTypeId: 62, ActivityName: "Strolling"}
```

I'm seeing all the examples use "label" and "value" but mine is typed from the server.  I'm assuming the problem is I need to specify what is the label & value, so I added the [optionLabel] tag but that didnt help.

Comment: Which version of PrimeNG do you use ?

Comment: "primeicons": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "primeng": "^6.0.0-rc.1",

Comment: Try to replace `[optionLabel]="ActivityName"` with `optionLabel="ActivityName"`.

Comment: @Antikhippe - yep that was it. thanks.